# XCode 3.2.6 Interface Builder Not Connecting

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, connection

In interface builder my outlets and ibactions won't connect. They simply won't show up, like it doesn't exist.

Here is my code:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UILabel *time;
    
}
-(IBAction)changetime;
```

In Interface Builder the only two connections there are is:

- view
- searchDisplayController.

  Please Help!

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue. Make sure you save (Shortcut: `Ctrl+S`) your `.h` before opening your `.xib` file.

Comment: @ Whoever [-1]ed, please always try to explain your reasons, as the author usually cannot guess what's wrong, and as such cannot address the issue and/or improve he's post. --- This applies in double when dealing with a new user, such as is the case, as to avoid a needless scare-away situation.